# SQL injection in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase is a noSQL database and works differently from SQL, so how we can sanitize the data? For example, i cant seem to find mysqli_real_escape_string command for firebase database even in firebase documentation. Can anyone advice me on this? Would also appreciate if anyone can drop me a forum link about this and etc. Hungry to know about this :> Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database (and Firestore) isn't vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

First, it's helpful to understand what SQL injection attacks are.  Please read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to help with your understanding.  Note that with SQL injection, the root problem is that the developer writes code has to build a SQL command to run, and the build (if not performed correctly) can be subtly modified by an attacker to do what they want.

With Firebase, you don't build a SQL command (or any string command composed of various parts that require escaping) in order to execute a query.  Instead, you use an API provided by the SDK, and pass strings that are automatically managed by the API.  This means that SQL injection is not an issue here.  There is no SQL injection because there is no SQL (it's noSQL after all!).

Ensure that end users have no more access to data than they are entitled, you need to use Firebase Authentication and implement [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) that describe who has access to what data.

Comment: Hi, appreciate your reply :D I know that firebase is json format and it does not require any SQL statement. However, can an attacker can use firebase command to extract the data from the firebase? maybe they will type something like this in the textbox var.on('value', snap => div.innertext = snap.val()); ??  I am not really familiar with firebase yet so i hope i am not asking stupid question but again thanks for explaining it to me :>

Comment: What you're describing isn't anything like SQL injection.  You need to take your own precautions to ensure that malicious scripts don't alter the end user experience.  If you want to ensure that end users have no more access to data than they are entitled, you need to use Firebase Authentication and implement security rules that describe who has access to what data. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: So it is safe to say that attackers are not able to mess with firebase database(at least on the front-end e.g website) as long as we set the rule types properly?

Comment: It's up to you to define those rules, yes.